# Open default file in vim if no argument given

Tags: vim

How do I configure vim to open a default file (in my case, `~/Desktop/now.md`) if the `vim` command is invoked without arguments on the command-line?

Comment: Create an alias in `.bash_profile`.

Comment: Depending on why you want to do this, you may find Vim's session handling to be a better approach (`:h Sessions`).

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `.vimrc`:

```
au VimEnter * if eval("@%") == "" | e ~/Desktop/now.md | endif
```

This tells vim that whenever you launch vim (`VimEnter`) with any filetype (`*`) to run the following ex command:

```
if eval("@%") == "" | e ~/Desktop/now.md | endif
```

This is pretty straight-forward. The register '%' holds the name of the file you are editing, so we evaluate it and see if it's empty. If it is, tell vim to open the specified file.

---

Recommended reading: [autocommands](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html)

Comment: Why are you using `eval()` here? Can you not simply access the `@%` register, e.g. `@!% == ""`. Alternatively you can use `argc()` to get the number of file passed into Vim using the `VimEnter` event as well, e.g. `autocmd VimEnter * if !argc() | e ~/Desktop/now.md | endif`. As @Niloct suggested you can use an bash alias. Which might be better if you try and script Vim (like use `-c`)

Comment: There are many problems with this approach.  One of them: you won't be able to use Vim to edit files opened from `stdin`.

Comment: You can't open folders anymore with this approach. Using argc (as @PeterRincker suggested)prevents this side effect.

Answer (score 0):

Might be simpler handle this in your shell instead of vim.

You can add something like this to your `.bash_profile` / `.zshrc`:

```
alias vim='if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then command vim ~/Desktop/now.md; else command vim "$@"; fi;'
```

1. `$#` is the number of parameters passed to the command
2. `"$@"` lists all parameters passed to the command
3. To avoid recursively calling the vim alias, we prepend the `vim` command with the `command` keyword, which avoids aliases.

Comment: I understand that doing it from the shell would be easier, but I was curious if it could be done entirely within vim.